# How to sectioning students after course timetabled using optaplanner

Tags: scheduling, optaplanner

I am new to OptaPlanner. There is an example of course scheduling of International Timetabling Competition 2007 Track 3. But no example to assign classes to students. Can anyone shed some light on this? Or tell me the pseudo code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The course scheduling example in optaplanner-examples ([see example code here](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/curriculumcourse)) assigns lectures to rooms and periods, the student assignment is already done because the students choose from a set of curricula themselves and each curriculum's courses are predefined.

There is no out of the box example to assign lectures (= classes) to students. It shouldn't be hard to build though, if there are sensible constraints.

Comment: Yes, Geoffrey, you are right. I think i can make out such a solution after i am more familiar with the wonderful optaplanner. Thank you!